# Doesn't work replaceText with regular expression in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Found a lot of information, where people say it should work like this:

```
var id = '/*doc ID here*/';
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
var body = doc.getBody();

var word = 'tototo'
var tempword = 'blablabla';
body.replaceText("\\b"+word+"\\b", tempword);
```

But it is not working.

Thу full idea is to find every word LALALA and make it a link, but don't make a link from words LALALAL or ALALALA etc.

```
function addLinks(word, siteurl) {
    var id = '/*doc ID here*/';
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
    var body = doc.getBody();

    var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2';
    var element = body.findText(word);
    // var element = body.findText("\\b"+word+"\\b");
   

    while(element) {
      var start = element.getStartOffset();
    
      var text = element.getElement().asText();
      text.replaceText("\\b"+word+"\\b", tempword);
      text.setLinkUrl(start, start+tempword.length-1, siteurl);
      
      var element = body.findText(word);

    }
    
    body.replaceText(tempword, word);
  }

addLinks('LALALA', 'example.com');
```

But it makes only one link and not from 1 word as needed, but from 16 letters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the text of `LALALA` and replace it with `var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2'`, and then, you want to set the hyperlink to `var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2'` in Google Document.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `addLinks` and test it again.

```js
function addLinks(word, siteurl) {
  var id = '/*doc ID here*/';
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2';
  var searchText = "\\b" + word + "\\b";
  var element = body.findText(searchText);
  while (element) {
    var start = element.getStartOffset();
    var text = element.getElement().asText();
    text.replaceText(searchText, tempword);
    text.setLinkUrl(start, start + tempword.length - 1, siteurl);
    element = body.findText(searchText, element);
  }
}
```

- In your script,

  - In order to search the next word of `word`, please use the method of `findText(searchPattern, from)`.
  - In your situation, I thought that the search work might be required to be also used as `"\\b" + word + "\\b"`.
  - `body.replaceText(tempword, word);` of the last line in `addLinks` replace `tempword` with `word`.
- When this modified script is run, the text of `LALALA` is searched and replaced it with `var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2'`, and then, the hyperlink is set to `var tempword = 'ASDFDSGDDKDSL2'`. On the other hand, `ALALALA` is not replaced.

#### Reference:

- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern-from)

Comment: It doesn't work. Unfortunately... Just nothing changes in a document.
If I change "\\b" + word + "\\b" to "LALALA" – it woks, but then ALALALA also becomes a link  excepting the first letter A, of course. So, it is a problem, that regular expression doesn't work, but I can't understand why...

Comment: I see what the problem now. In my regular expression I use Cyrillic symbols (LALALA is an example here). What's is the problem with Russian letters?

Comment: @Vsevolod Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, now I found [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69511092). I will check it.